# React TimePicker not scrolling on Modal

Tags: reactjs, timepicker, antd

https://codesandbox.io/s/6lol2kz3v3

When the modal is scrolled, the timepicker just stays on the same position instead of getting scrolled together with the other components.

What would be the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with adding the prop `getPopupContainer={triggerNode => triggerNode.parentNode}` to the component.